# Como faço para ativar o TimeSpan com um horario definido

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

eu queria fazer um TimeSpan definido, tipo assim das 8:00 as 8:10 e depois das 16:00 as 16:10 ele fica mandando um mensagebox que eu criei, fora de esses horarios não é para aparecer.

```
var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Zero;
var periodTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
{
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Teste de Mensagem");
    },
    null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
}
```

Ae eu queria colocar essa condição em algum if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pelo o que entendi vc quer isso:

```
 var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) =>
                {
                    if ((DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= System.TimeSpan.Parse("08:00:00.000") && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= System.TimeSpan.Parse("08:10:00.000")) 
|| (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay >= System.TimeSpan.Parse("16:00:00.000") && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay <= System.TimeSpan.Parse("16:10:00.000")))
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Teste de Mensagem");
                        }
                    },
                    null, startTimeSpan, periodTimeSpan);
```

Comment: Acho que a logica da sua programação esta certa, mas ele continua aparecendo a mensagem em qualquer período, não nos determinados

Comment: @WesleyHenrique I saw the problem now, it is about my copy and paste

Comment: @WesleyHenrique try now, i just correct the >= and the time of 16

Comment: Eu corrigi e funcionou, valeu cara

Comment: @WesleyHenrique marca a resposta como aceita, lado esquedo no checkbox :)

Comment: Será que eu consigo implementar em um sistema asp.net para enviar um email nesse período?

Comment: @WesleyHenrique sim.

Comment: Ae eu teria que iniciar ele no APP_Start, com a configuração do email?

Comment: no lugar do msgbox vai chama a funcao para fazer o envio de email.

Comment: Foi isso que eu fiz, vou testar para ver se ele funcionar só no servidor e não em cada maquina que o sistema abrir

Comment: No asp.net não funciona.